# Loading an error message to the next view

Tags: laravel, session-variables, flash-message

I have a controller that is accessing an external API to load data, when a certain page is loaded. Now I wanted to have an error message being displayed when the page is loaded but the external API was not accessible.

To load an error message to the session I am using the  response from Pavel Lint to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690463/best-way-to-store-error-messages-in-laravel-session-or-variable) question to create the following function:

```php
/**
* Add an error array to the MessageBag in the 
* ViewErrorBag of the session
* 
* @param array|null $errors
*/
private static function addErrorsToSession($errors) {
        
   if (!is_null($errors)) {
        $sessionErrors = Session::get('errors', new ViewErrorBag);

        if (! $sessionErrors instanceof ViewErrorBag) {
            $sessionErrors = new ViewErrorBag;
        }

        $bag = $sessionErrors->getBags()['default'] ?? new MessageBag;
        foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
            $bag->add($key, $value);
        }

        Session::flash(
            'errors', $sessionErrors->put('default', $bag)
        );
    }
}
```

Then in the controller function to load the view is

```php
/**
* Show the create form.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function create()
{
    $errors = [
        'error_key' => 'this is a test'
    ];

    $this->addErrorsToSession($errors);

    return view('resource.create');
}
```

The message is shown in the view by

```php
error('error_key')
    <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>    
@enderror
```

On the initial page load the error message does not appear.
Only when I refresh the page the message gets through.
How can I get the message to also pop-up on the initial page load?

I am aware that I could return the vie `withErrors` as

```php
return view('resource.create')->withErrors($errors);
```

but I would like to have a way to add an error to the session without access to the view.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800744/laravel-flash-message-showing-after-refresh

Comment: the middleware that "shares errors with the views" has already ran before you even get to your controller ... you would have to directly pass it to the view in your case as the session was already checked for errors beforehand .. the reason the next "view" gets the errors is because at that point a new request is passing through the middleware stack and there are errors to share from the session at that point

Comment: also you are 'flashing' session data which is only available on the next request (as opposed to just setting session data directly, which would have to be flushed/removed explicitly) ... which the link above has my answer too already  .... usually flashing session data goes along with redirecting

Comment: @StewieSWS thank you very much!
@lagbox so how does `withErrors` make sure the error gets through to the current view? Is there an easy way to emulate it?